# API not responding

Tags: javascript, ajax

The app that I'm working on does not respond with the API address. I only get the ajax responding, but not the weather api that I'm trying to call.

I've tried everything that I could think of with my current knowledge.

```
let search = document.getElementById("search-bar");
let temp = document.getElementById("temperature");
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let city = document.getElementById("city");
const key = "";

input.addEventListener("keyup", enter);

function enter(event) {
    if (event.key==="Enter") {
        details();
    }
}

function details() {
    if (searchInput.value === ""){
    } else {
        let searchLink = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}" + searchInput.value + "&appid=" + key;
        httpRequestAsync(searchLink, talk)
    }
}

function talk(talking){
    let jsonObject = JSON.parse(talking);
    city.innerHTML = jsonOject.name;
    temp.innerHTML = parseInt(parseInt(jsonObject.main.temp - 273) + "°");
}

function httpRequestAsync(url,callback){
    var httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => { 
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
            callback(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
    request.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous 
    request.send();
}
```

The expected outcome should be the weather api being called and displayed information in the console.

Comment: Are there errors in console or what is actually happening?

Comment: Look. You define `httpRequest`, then call `request` in your `httpRequestAsync`

Comment: There are no errors in the console. If there was I'd actrually know what direction to take, but the console shows nothing. No response from the weather api that's called.

Comment: I advice you to remove your API key

Comment: you named your variable `search`
(`let search=document.getElementById("search-bar");`)
and then ask for the value of `searchInput`
(`if (searchInput.value===""){`)
try to use the same name at the 2 spots

Comment: @Kevin.a Too late, better generate a new api key. It will always be visible in the edit history

Comment: Your query is wrong btw. It should be   searchLink="https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+searchInput.value+"&appid="+key;

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code should produce a message about `searchInput` causing a ReferenceError.

Comment: There's simply a bunch of "typos" in there. `searchInput`/`search`, `jsonOject`, `httpRequest`/`request`. Fixing those is enough, the rest of the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing last function with this:

```
function httpRequestAsync(url,callback){
    var httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => { 
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200)
            callback(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
    httpRequest.open("GET", url, true); // true for asynchronous 
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

I just corrected variable naming

Comment: That's not the only variable naming issue though.